# Convert xml to clob by maintaining formatting Oracle11g

Tags: xml, clob, oracle11gr2, xmltype

I have to store a variable of xmltype into a clob. I am using getclobval() function to convert the xml into clob.
However, the data gets stored as a string in the clob and the formatting is lost.
Is there any way I can preserve xml format while converting xmltype to clob?

```
select xmlelement(info,xmlelement(name,'Sankalp'),xmlelement(surname,'Patil')) into xml1 from dual; 
dbms_output.put_line(xml1.getClobval);
```

Output:

```
<INFO><NAME>Sankalp</NAME><SURNAME>Patil</SURNAME></INFO>
```

I am expecting output as:

```
<INFO>
  <NAME>Sankalp</NAME>
  <SURNAME>Patil</SURNAME>
</INFO>
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: What "formatting" are we talking about?  I'm assuming the original whitespace in the document?  From your description, it sounds like you are saying that the formatting is lost when you store the data in the CLOB column which implies that the `getClobVal()` function is returning a CLOB that includes the formatting you want.  Is that accurate?  If that is what you are saying, it would be surprising to me.  Is the `XMLType` variable coming from a table?  If so, how is that table storing XML data (`CLOB`, binary XML, object-relational?)

Comment: You'll need to edit your question (and probably format the edit correctly).  I don't see any difference between the expected and actual output.  Are you really constructing the XMLType from a query?  Or are you loading data from an XML file into the XMLType?

Comment: Why do you expect the output to have additional whitespace?  The query you've written doesn't appear to do anything to inject additional whitespace so it doesn't appear that there is any whitespace to maintain.  If you run the `SELECT` statement in a SQL*Plus session (without the `into xml1` of course), you'll get an XML document that has no extra whitespace.

Comment: the xmldata is being generated dynamically by xmlelement function as i have shown in the sample code.

Comment: if a create a column with xmltype datatype, the output is getting stored in correct xml format. to sum it up again, i want to generate xml using xmltype function, store it as a clob and when the downstream application reads this clob, it should have the xml formatting.

Comment: so, do i have to do something more in the query to add the additional whitespace and newline characters you mean Justin?

Comment: any suggestions please? already written a lot of code to prepare tens of xml strings. now the developer who is going to use it says the unformatted clob won't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

This did the job finally:

```
select xmlserialize(content v_xmltype as clob indent size = 2 ) 
 into v_clob_data from dual;
```

fyi, Oracle suggests to use xmlserialize than getclobval.

Comment: Can be done in this manner also:   
   SELECT xmltype.EXTRACT (var1_xmltype, '/*') INTO var2_xmltype FROM DUAL;
   var3_clob := var2.getclobval;